# Set focus on PropertySheet Item Node in ControlsFX

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx, propertysheet

I want to set focus on `PropertySheet.Item` Node (for example `TextField`) in ControlsFX. PropertySheet Item have unique name, so i can find `PropertySheet.Item` with code `propertySheet.getItems().get(i).getName()`. But there is no API to get `Node` which corresponds to property item. The only solution i see is to [walk scene graph](http://www.kware.net/?p=8) with method `getChildrenUnmodifiable`. But when i traverse `PropertySheet` with this method it returns:

```
PropertySheet@1ab0e7e0[styleClass=property-sheet]
BorderPane@46e1b462
ToolBar@93ba99a[styleClass=tool-bar]
SegmentedButton@d5c968[styleClass=segmented-button]
HBox@1c3283db
ToggleButton@2fffaccc[styleClass=toggle-button left-pill]''
```

I don't get any Propertysheet Nodes such as `TextField` or `ComboBox`. Is it possible to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
You must use `setPropertyEditorFactory` and global hashmap variable which will store all Nodes, so you can access it later. Sample code below.

```
public Map<String, Node> nodes = new HashMap<>();

    SimpleObjectProperty<Callback<PropertySheet.Item, PropertyEditor<?>>> propertyEditorFactory = 
new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "propertyEditor", new DefaultPropertyEditorFactory());

    propertySheet.setPropertyEditorFactory((PropertySheet.Item param) -> {
       PropertyEditor node = propertyEditorFactory.get().call(param);
       nodes.put(uniquePropertyName, node.getEditor());
       return node;
    });
```

After this you can focus property Node with:

```
nodes.get(propertyName).requestFocus();
```